# How do I track what registry changes is done to the system by an install shield installer?

Tags: registry, installshield

I need something like i6comp but for list of reg changes rather than list of files.

Does such a thing exist?

EDIT:I know there are ways to do monitor changes to the ergistry but are there ways to do it by examining the setup files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to log and compare Windows Registry data before and after any program installation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911689/how-to-log-and-compare-windows-registry-data-before-and-after-any-program-instal)

Answer (score 7):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

[RegMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx)

Comment: Note: FileMon and RegMon have been replaced by Process Monitor on versions of Windows starting with Windows 2000 SP4, Windows XP SP2, Windows Server 2003 SP1, and Windows Vista. FileMon and RegMon remain for legacy operating system support, including Windows 9x

Answer (score 1):

You can check the registry tables in the MSI using something like Orca but thats not guaranteed to catch all possible changes to the registry.

The only sure way is comparing pre and post install changes using somethink like RegMon.

Answer (score 0):

1. Export the registry.

   - Run installer.
   - Export the registry to a different file
   - Compare the two files with your favorite comparison program.

Comment: Hi Greg,
 Let me know, which one is easiest way to compare two export reg files ...that is to be appreciative ...