# How to log and compare Windows Registry data before and after any program installation?

Tags: windows, registry, windows-installer, installshield

I need to compare the windows registry data before and after install a program ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

RegShot !

http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to have **[Total Commander](http://ghisler.com/)**, this is pretty easy:

1. export the registry before the installation and after the installation (save with the same name in different folders)
2. open both folders in Total Commander, highlight the file on one side, go to **Files** > **Compare By Content...** voilá:

[image]

*Total Commander is shareware, try before you buy.*

Comment: I copied this answer from http://superuser.com/a/79576/93378 It works really well.

Answer (score 1):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) works perfectly for that (and you can also log filesystem activity).

Comment: Procmon (and specifically the Regmon piece of Procmon, for this question) is what I've always seen used in a professional setting.